# Understanding a billing's message

Tags: meaning-in-context, finance, money, sentence-meaning

It's important and I want to make sure I understand it correctly before replying or reacting in any way.

> Hello,
>
> John here from billing.
>
> Thank you for your patience while we reviewed your case. After a
>   detailed review, I've found that those instances has been deleted, I’m
>   pleased to inform you that we’ve approved a billing adjustment of 400
>   USD for charges on your January bill, which has been applied as a
>   credit to your account. This credit will automatically apply and can
>   be referenced in the following link...

Does it mean they dropped my billings? The language is somewhat unclear to me.

A little background: I had a billing of 310$ that seemed to keep getting bigger even though I canceled their service when it reached 270$ or so.
Now it seems that this service's billing was removed from my billings page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means they are giving you a $400 credit which will be automatically applied to your billing account.

So if your outstanding bill was -$310, and now you get a +$400 credit, then your now have a +$90 credit left on your account.

Comment: It looks contextually likely (given John from billing said *Thank you for your patience*) that by the time they finished reviewing the case, the erroneous billings had reached $400 (or thereabouts - if it was *much* less one might have expected John to say that they were making an additional adjustment by way of compensation for the inconvenience). So OP probably shouldn't be looking for +$90 credit on his account.